# missing type in composite literal go AND missing key in map literal go

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, go, mongo-go

Im trying to do Pagination with MongoDB

I write this code:

```
findOptions := options.Find()
    findOptions.SetLimit(20)
    findOptions.SetSort(bson.M{{"_id", 1}})

    cursor, err34 := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{{"_id", bson.M{{"$gte", last_id}}}}, findOptions)
```

Now
It keeps complaining:

> missing type in composite literal go AND missing key in map literal go

It complains for this part:

```
findOptions.SetSort(bson.M{{"_id", 1}})
```

and

```
bson.M{{"_id", bson.M{{"$gte", last_id}}}}, findOptions)
```

I'm stuck with this error since so many hours and its very frustrating.

Please Help :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`bson.M`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M) is a map:

```
type M map[string]interface{}
```

So use the map [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) syntax to create a value of it:

```
bson.M{"_id": 1}
```

And:

```
bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$gte": last_id}}
```