# How to replace a document in MongoDB with Go driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go, mongo-go-driver

I'm trying to update a document in MongoDB with `mongodb/mongo-go-driver`. From its doc, one document can be replaced with:

```golang
var coll *mongo.Collection
var id primitive.ObjectID

// find the document for which the _id field matches id and add a field called "location"
// specify the Upsert option to insert a new document if a document matching the filter isn't found
opts := options.Replace().SetUpsert(true)
filter := bson.D{{"_id", id}}
replacement := bson.D{{"location", "NYC"}}
result, err := coll.ReplaceOne(context.TODO(), filter, replacement, opts)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

if result.MatchedCount != 0 {
    fmt.Println("matched and replaced an existing document")
    return
}
if result.UpsertedCount != 0 {
    fmt.Printf("inserted a new document with ID %v\n", result.UpsertedID)
}
```

But what if I have fields more than like 20. I am wondering if I can update without re-writing all fields again, I tried something like this:

```golang
// Replacement struct
type Input struct {
    Name        *string `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty" validate:"required"`
    Description *string `json:"description,omitempty" bson:"description,omitempty"`
    Location    *string `json:"location,omitempty" bson:"location,omitempty"`
}

... 
oid, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(id) // because 'id' from request is string
filter := bson.M{"_id", oid} // throws `[compiler] [E] missing key in map literal`
//                      ^^^
replacement := bson.D{{"$set", input}} // throws `composite literal uses unkeyed fields`
//                             ^^^^^
result, err := coll.ReplaceOne(context.TODO(), filter, replacement, opts)
...
```

But it throws errors at filter and replacement. How can I replace a whole document properly?

Comment: `bson.M` is a map, so if you use it, you have to write: `bson.M{"_id": oid}`. And `bson.D` is a slice of structs, so if you use it, you should write `bson.D{{Key:"$set", Value: input}}`. Omitting the field names is not a compiler error, it's just a `go vet` warning.

Comment: @icza I did what you said, but it throws `"message": "replacement document cannot contains keys beginning with '$"` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bson.M`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M) is a map, so if you use it, you have to write: `bson.M{"_id": oid}`. See [missing type in composite literal go AND missing key in map literal go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226091/missing-type-in-composite-literal-go-and-missing-key-in-map-literal-go/64226163#64226163).

And [`bson.D`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) is a slice of structs, so if you use it, you should write `bson.D{{Key:"$set", Value: input}}`. Omitting the field names is not a compiler error, it's just a go vet warning.

Now on to replacing. The replacement must be a document itself, without using `$set` (this is not updating but replacing). For reference see MongoDB's [`collection.replaceOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/) and the driver's doc: [`Collection.ReplaceOne()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.2/mongo#Collection.ReplaceOne):

> The replacement parameter must be a document that will be used to replace the selected document. It cannot be nil and cannot contain any update operators (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/).

So do it like this:

```
filter := bson.M{"_id": oid}
result, err := coll.ReplaceOne(context.TODO(), filter, input, opts)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete code. This will help readers to understand the code flow.

```golang
func UpdateFunction(echoCtx echo.Context) (error) {

//Web Section
    documentID := echoCtx.Param("id")   //Provided in URL

    var newObject myStruct
    err := echoCtx.Bind(&newObject)  // Json with updated values sent by web client mapped to struct

    ctx := echoCtx.Request().Context()

//Database Section
    database := db.Conn.Database("myDatabase")
    collection := database.Collection("myCollection")

    existingHexID, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(documentID)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ObjectIDFromHex ERROR", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("ObjectIDFromHex:", existingHexID)
    }

    // Replacing OLD document with new using _id
    filter := bson.M{"_id": newDocumentID}
    result, err := collection.ReplaceOne(ctx, filter, newObject)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf(
        "insert: %d, updated: %d, deleted: %d /n",
        result.MatchedCount,
        result.ModifiedCount,
        result.UpsertedCount,
    )

    return echoCtx.JSON(http.StatusOK, result.ModifiedCount)
}
```